# Why data not appearing in HTML fields when using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I am completely fresher in knockout.js and just started . I just created a simple page in asp.net form application . and put following scripts and HTML .

when i run this code fields are still showing blank

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var product = { itemNumber: "T314CE", model: "Taylor 314ce", salePrice: 1199.95 };
        ko.applyBindings(product);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>
            With Knockout</h2>
        <span>Item number</span><span data-bind="text: itemNumber"></span>
        <br />
        <span>Guitar model:</span><input data-bind="value: model" />
        <span>Sales price:</span><input data-bind="value: salePrice" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

no js error ? How can i find the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function on document.ready or you can put the script block at the bottom of your HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

rahularyansharma your binding executes before your DOM load.. so it never works untill it will exceute inside the document.ready or page bottom script area.